# PHP - How to transpose an array that is from a text file

Tags: php, arrays, transpose

We have made an array from a text file full of numbers separated by commas, each new line is a new part of the array. **(we are not allowed to use explode for this)**
We are trying to create a transpose_matrix function to 'transpose' the array now.
Using tutorials on the internet, this is what we have come up with so far, but it doesn't work :(

```
$myfile = fopen("text1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
//echo fread($myfile,filesize("text1.txt"));
$file1 = file("text1.txt");
$store1 = array();

for ($a = 0; $a<count($file1); $a++)
    {
        array_push($store1, $file1[$a]);
    }
for ($k = 0; $k<count($store1); $k++)
    {
        echo "Line $store1[$k] <br/> END <br/>"; 
    }

function transpose($store1) {
    $file1 = file("text1.txt");
    $store1 = array();

    if (count($store1) == 0) // special case: empty matrix
        return array();
    else if (count($store1) == 1) // special case: row matrix
        return array_chunk($store1[0], 1);

    function myCallbackMethod() {
        var_dump ($store1);
    }

    array_unshift($store1, NULL); // the original matrix is not modified because it was passed by value
    return call_user_func_array('myCallbackMethod',$store1);
}

transpose($store1);

fclose($myfile); 

}
```

Comment: Post some sample  contents in the file

Comment: Edit the post, paste the code, use code format button to highlight it properly.

Comment: heard about `str_getcsv` ? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.str-getcsv.php

Comment: Your first `for` loop is equivalent to `$store1 = $file1;`. You seem to be missing the code that's supposed to replace the call to `explode()`.

Comment: Why does `transpose()` call `file()`? It received the contents of the file as an argument.

Comment: We are new to php. I am not sure what you mean by this ?

Comment: explode by line, then by commas, then add to lines array the array of values resulting from the exploding line by commas. that's as simple as this. take care of the empty file case, and empty line case.

Answer (score 0):

Try reading with [fscanf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fscanf.php).
something like

```
fscanf($file_link, '%s\n', $temp);
array_push($array, $temp);
```

should work.

Sukhdev Mohan